# How to display an entire incoming string from the serial monitor in arduino ide?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, arduino-ide

this is my first question in this forum.

I need to receive a string from the Arduino serial monitor and display it when the communication is over. I have a similar problem like the one discussed in this thread:

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/45543/how-do-i-receive-an-entire-string-as-opposed-to-1-character-at-a-time-on-the-ard

Only I'm using the Arduino serial monitor instead of a RaspberryPi to send strings so I can't program the sender to attach an identifier like '\n' at the end of the string.

```
char inData[20];
char inChar=-1;
byte index = 0;

while (Serial.available() > 0){
  ending[1]=ending[1]+1;
  if(index < 19){

      inChar = Serial.read();
      inData[index] = inChar;
      index++;
      inData[index] = '\0';
      Serial.flush();   
  }
  Serial.print(inData);Serial.print("\t");Serial.println();
}
```

What I receive in the console looks like this:

```
M
Me  
Mes 
Mess    
Messa   
Messag
Message
```

I need to display only the final string

```
Message
```

The code has to know when the incoming string ended and then display it once.

I'd really appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: You have two options. The most reliable is to decide that a particular character will serve as an end-of-message indicator. `\n` is a common choice, but you can choose whatever you are not going to use in the message itself. The other option is to have a timeout: if no further characters have been received for XXX ms, then assume the message is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want a string. Try using `Serial.readString()`. It will return the full string.

The code could look like this:

```
if(Serial.available()  > 0)
{
  String message = Serial.readString();
  Serial.println(message);
}
```

Comment: It is worth noting that `Stream::readString()` works with a timeout, which is 1 second by default, but can be changed with `setTimeout()`.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed. Now the output in the serial monitor is the entire text input. First post, first issue solved. I'm really grateful.